# Firebase - Push Notifications - Not quite working as expected

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

In order to try out Push Notifications with Firebase I have been following these three documents:
[One](https://www.appcoda.com/firebase-push-notifications/), [Two](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/dc2cd2db6e82e5c475fa3f0efe75df8b54f04544/messaging/MessagingExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift#L40-L55), [Three](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-the-usernotifications-framework--cms-27250) and [Four](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging).

I have one question, but before asking; here is what I can see:

When my app is in the foreground and a notification is sent, only this function is called:

```
userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:)
```

If I tap on the notification, then this one is also so called:

```
userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)
```

When my app is in the background and a notification is sent, nothing is called.

If I tap on the notification, then this one is called:

```
userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)
```

As a result of this situation, whithout having to react (by tapping on the notification); I can have the app perform some useful action when a notification is arriving while in the foreground, using the *userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:)* function.

On the other hand while in the background, I can only have the app perform some useful action when a notification is arriving if the user taps on the notification.

Is there a way for me to also have the app perform some useful action even if the user has no reaction?

Here is the relevant code I have at this point:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseMessaging


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {
                granted, error in
                if error != nil {print("Error: \(error!)")}

                if granted {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async
                        {application.registerForRemoteNotifications()}
                }
        })

        FirebaseApp.configure()
        .......

        return true
    }


    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        print(#function)
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
    }


    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        print(#function)
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
}
```

For information, I am using Xcode Version 10.1, iOS 12.1  and Swift 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

**swift 4.2, Xcode 10.0, IOS 12.0**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseMessaging

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .alert , .sound]) { (granted, error) in
                let type: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.badge, UIUserNotificationType.alert, UIUserNotificationType.sound]
                let setting = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: type, categories: nil)
                UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(setting)
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        } else {
            let type: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.badge, UIUserNotificationType.alert, UIUserNotificationType.sound]
            let setting = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: type, categories: nil)
            UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(setting)
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        if(FIRApp.defaultApp() == nil){
            FIRApp.configure()
        }
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification(notification:)),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name.firInstanceIDTokenRefresh,
                                               object: nil)

        return true
    }


    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo as? NSDictionary
        _ = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let aps = userInfo?["aps"] as! NSDictionary
    }

    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    // Convert token to string

    let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
    print("Device Token", deviceTokenString)
    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.unknown)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification data: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
    let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let aps = data["aps"] as! NSDictionary
    let state = UIApplication.shared.applicationState
    if state == .background {
    }
    if state == .active {
    }
}

//MARK: Notification Center Call
func callNotificationCenter(){
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "reloadData"), object: nil)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
}

// start firebase
@objc func tokenRefreshNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()
    print(refreshedToken)
    connectToFcm()
}

func connectToFcm() {
    FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")

        } else {
            print("Connected to FCM")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK. So which function in this code is going to be called when a notification arrives while the app is in background and the user does nothing?

Comment: didReceiveRemoteNotification

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I quickly tried to compile your code to see how it works, but it appears to use an older API than mine (Probably because the pods you are using are older). Can you please point in my code what it is that I need to change to make things work the way I want?

Comment: use the latest pods.

Comment: Yes, I think that's what I am doing.